Generalize the probability of finding a particle in a certain range, starting from the 1D case
I'm working on my thesis and I'm writing the calculations of the probability that a neutron have to interacts, inside a media, on the x-axis, between $x$ and $x+dx$. I worked out easily this quantity, since if $p(x+dx)$ is the probability of interaction and $w dx$ is the probability of no interaction, it's possible to write
\begin{equation}
p(x+dx)=p(x)(1-w dx).
\end{equation}
Manipulating this expression leads to an exponential pdf $p(x)=w e^{-w x}$, where $w$ is the inverse of the mean free path. Now I'm trying to work out this relation for a generic displacement in the three-dimensional space $\vec{r}$. I've done some calculation, but I'm not sure how to treat the non interacting term this time. Can you help me?
In the current calculation I've just tried to write $p(\vec{r}+d \vec{r})=p(\vec{r}) + \vec{\nabla} p(\vec{r})\cdot d \vec{r}$, the non interacting term as $\vec w\cdot d \vec r $ and substituting them in an equation similar to the previous one.
